# How to convert 12~24Vdc range input to steady 12V, 5V and 3,3V for beginners

Tags: power, power-electronics, arm, industrial

This is my first try in the power management world - I always used ready to run power supplies to my devices, so here is my current chalenge:

I have a prototype for an industrial device that is required to be powered directly by machines in the field. Those machines works in a 12-24Vdc range, so my input must be of that voltage range.

The device has positioning sensors that uses 12Vdc.

Currently I'm using Raspberry PI with a 7pol LCD monitor via HDMI to prototype, so I'm using an external double power supply applying 5Vdc for the Raspberry board/LCD and 12Vdc for the sensor - all fine. The 5Vdc power goes to Raspberry and then I have HDMI and USB cables to the monitor. 12Vdc goes directly to the sensor. Grounds together.

My final goal is to build an all in one custom board - and I need to provide the power conversion circuit. The end design will use and ARM Cortexprocessor (3,3Vdc) and its associates (SD Card, controllers, GPIO opto isolators, etc). The board will have connectors to the industrial sensors (12Vdc), an HDMI and USB output to the external 7pol monitor.

So, I will input 12-24Vdc to the board and I need power to handle all of my necessities: the ARM processor and its associated components, the 12Vdc industrial sensor and the LCD monitor.

I need also something robust and temperature safe, as I will be working on industrial environment (hot hash environment, but manufacturing shop floors)

I need to know where to start from, get some suggestions on how to build that circuit and advices on further docs to learn how to do it. Are there IC's that would help me on that? Do I need something special, non standard?

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be to use a 12-24V to 12V buck converter to make +12V, then to make +5V use either a 12-24V buck from the input 12-24V supply or a 12V to 5V buck from the 12V supply.

This has several problems.

First, the 12V rail goes out of the board to the sensors, and if there is a short on these wires, it will also kill any other rails derived from it like the micro's power supply. Thus in this case the board will just power down instead of displaying a helpful error message or raising an alarm. To fix this you can use current limiters, polyswitch fuses, or not derive the internal rails (micro, etc) from the sensor power. It is good practice that when some of the sensor wires are shorted together, your board should at least not destroy itself, and preferably keep running to alert the user.

Then, most buck chips have a maximum duty cycle which is not 100%, so they do have a "dropout voltage" just like a LDO. In addition, even if the top MOSFET in your buck converter would stay on continuously, there would still be voltage drop due to the MOSFET and inductor's resistances.

This means a buck converter (or a LDO) can't have an output voltage equal to input voltage, although some have pretty low dropout.

In addition you may want to relax your "12V-24V" input a little bit, say 10-30V, because a 12V or 24V supply is never exact, there may be some voltage dips or spikes, someone may want to use it with "24V" batteries which are much higher than 24V when fully charged, etc.

So the main problem is getting "12V" that will satisfy the 12V sensors, while handling the input voltage in a robust way that "just works" even if it's a bit low.

These days everything is low voltage so maybe your "12V" sensors will be specified to work fine on a much wider range of voltage, in this case you can use a buck converter to go from say "11-30V" on the input to "10.5-12V" for the sensors.

Another option would be a buck from the input voltage down to 5V, then a boost to 12V for the sensors. Or a buck-boost converter to get a stable 12V no matter what.

If the sensors don't use much power, you can even use a LDO for the same purpose.

So, OK, I didn't really answer the question, but I think you should:

- List the loads you want to power with their full supply spec (maximum and minimum voltage) plus maximum supply current.
- Have a rough idea of the efficiency you need, how much power you can waste as heat, what's your compromise on cost and complexity versus efficiency, etc. Quite often a more expensive switching solution ends up cheaper than a LDO because getting rid of heat is cumbersome and expensive.
- Think about what supply rails will be exposed on connectors and especially on sensor wires and may get shorted, and what should happen if they do.

--

OK so:

> Input sensors - One model can work from 10 to 30Vdc,200mA, another model: 6-36Vdc, 300mA.

So you could power them directly from the input supply. Otherwise, you can use a buck chip with a high maximum duty cycle to reduce dropout voltage when supply voltage is low. For example LMR51420 has 98% max duty cycle so on 10V input you lose 0.2V plus resistive losses. A way to find these chips is to use the parametric search on the manufacturer website, most have something like [TI Webench](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator) where you can enter an input range like 11-30V and select an output voltage of 10.5V: that will automatically filter out the chips with unsuitable maximum duty cycle. Also consider maximum current etc, of course.

Then to power your micro, display, etc, you'll need lower voltages.

As said above, if you generate these from the sensor power which is also exported out of the box with wires, then you need to protect it with a current limiting chip, load switch, or polyswitch that will trip fast enough to prevent the 12V rail from dipping too much if there is a short on the external wires.

So it would probably be simpler to generate your lower voltage rails directly from the input voltage, and count on the buck chip's overcurrent protection to handle shorts: in this case if there is a short the 12V rail will go to zero but the micro will still be powered.

However, if the +12V output is shorted to +24V, the 12V buck chip will see an excessive output voltage: if it's a synchronous buck chip it will thus turn on its lower MOSFET permanently in an attempt to fix this problem and it will be destroyed. In order to protect against this, you need to either use a non-synchronous buck chip (the old kind, with a diode) which will just shut down if Vout is shorted to Vin, or revert to the above solution of using a load switch/current limit/e-fuse chip with reverse polarity protection...

Comment: OK, some more data: Input sensors - Onde model can work from 10 to 30Vdc,200mA, another model: 6-36Vdc, 300mA. Models may change, but I want to keep it around industrial specs (are there specific specs for that?). Input current 10-30Vdc is also very acceptable - I agree about industrial loads and batteries. Regarding size and heat, I would like to keep the size small and avoid handling dissipation inside the board or in the case itself. I plan to use ABS case. About the supply short circuit, this is a possibility as we will have exposed power connector (USB, GPIO), so this is a main worries..